# Authenticate email messages PHP (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

When sending emails from a server, but labelling them as 'from' the provided email address (such as for a contact form where you wish the 'reply-to' to be the person who actually sent it) gmail and perhaps some other services flag these as potentially harmful if they weren't authenticated by gmail (or the relevant mail provider).

This is good, naturally, however Google offer a workaround for this to avoid the phishing warning, by giving the following advice:

> "If the email wasn't sent with Gmail, but the sender includes authentication data in the message, we'll show you the sender's name and the service that authenticated the message.".

They also provide a screenshot example of how it displays, using a 'via' addition to explain that the email originated from somewhere different.

What they don't explain is how you do this. How do I 'authenticate' emails sent from CodeIgniter (or the server, depending on how it's achieved I guess)? Google hasn't been that helpful for me this morning, I'm getting a lot of FAQ type results that are clearly consumer focussed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've found the issue is that there are a few factors involved.

Gmail, for example, requires that emails are signed with RSA 1024-bit encryption to trigger the `via domain.tld` message, instead of the phishing warning. My current server setup uses RSA 256-bit encryption, which Google classifies as a 'short key' and doesn't count as authenticated anymore, I assume because it's too easy to spoof. Media Temple informs me that the longer key encryption is achieved through an SSL certificate (although I don't know if this is a technical requirement, perhaps someone can elaborate).

So the short answer is that what qualifies as 'authenticated' will vary from receiver to receiver. But hopefully this information is useful to someone else!

Comment: This question is really old now, but there's still the matter of HOW. How do you do anything you just talked about in this answer?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the SMTP server is what authenticates the emails, not codeigniter (unless you built your own smtp server).

In short, When sending through any other SMTP server, you'll get a 'via' added to it.
So the question that stands is who are you sending the emails through?

Comment: It's our own mail server. Just a standard setup from within plesk on a media temple DV4. So clearly not 'any' SMTP sever, must be more to it than that.

Comment: The quote mentions authentication data. Maybe there's a header or something?

Comment: I have no experience in that honestly, What i wrote came from my own experience of working with various SMTP servers(be it google, mandrill etc.)
all of those added the 'via' automatically for me.

sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Comment: No problem! After further searching it seems like it might require specific server-side technology, so it might just be that the default mail setup on my server doesn't have it. Seems like it's more common with larger and more dedicated mail hosts, but information is a little sparse. Either way it doesn't look like a simple task, unfortunately.

Comment: FYI Further reading indicates that in my case it could be that the encryption uses 256-bit keys, and Google wants 1024-bit keys. So my emails are signed and authenticated, but not to the standard the receiver wants.